# Adding values to an ocaml list based on its existing values

Tags: list, pattern-matching, ocaml

I'm learning about the map and fold functions. I'm trying to write a function that takes a list and returns a list with all of the values in the original, each followed by that value's double.

```
Example: add_dbls [2;5;8] = [2;4;5;10;8;16]
```

Everything I try results in a list of lists, instead of a list. I'm struggling to come up with a better approach, using either map or fold (or both).

This is what I came up with originally. I understand why this returns a list of lists, but can't figure out how to fix it. Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
let add_dbls list = 
    match list with
    | h::t -> map (fun a-> [a;(a*2)]) list
    | [] -> []
```

Also, my map function:

```
let rec map f list =
    match list with
    | h::t -> (f h)::(map f t)
    | [] -> []
```

Comment: I've reverted the question to its original state. Please don't alter the meaning of the question after you have received an answer, since it alters the meaning of the answer as well when it loses its original context. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is intended as a knowledge base of useful questions and answers, not your personal help desk. You should instead either ask a new question or alternatively add to the original question if it builds on the context of it. Please also take the [tour] to get a better understanding of what SO is about.

Comment: Personally, I would simply build the list containing all the doubles (using `List.map`), and then concatenate the original list with the new one.

Comment: @glennsl Apologies, I was merely responding to the original first answer, as the changed question is the same question just a new attempt by me. Will add to questions instead of changing them in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's should be simple to see that `List.map` always returns a list of the same length as the input list. But you want a list that's twice as long. So `List.map` cannot work for you.

You can solve this using `List.fold_left` or `List.fold_right`. If you're still having trouble after you switch to using a fold, you could update your question with the new information.

**Update**

The type of your fold function (a left fold) is this:

```
('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a
```

So, the folded function takes an accumulated answer and an element of the list, and it returns a new accumulated answer.

Your folded function is like this:

```
fun a b -> a::b::(b*2)
```

It attempts to use the `::` operator to add new elements to the end of the accumulated list. But that's not what the `::` operator does. It adds an element to the *beginning* of a list.

There's no particularly nice way to add an element to the end of a list. This is intentional, because it's a slow operation.

When using a left fold, you need to reconcile yourself to building up the result in reverse order and possibly reversing it at the end. Or you can use a right fold (which is generally not tail recursive).

Comment: I hadn't considered that about the map function. I've tried working with fold as well, and still cannot come up with something that works. I think I'm missing something in my arguments or building of the list?

I've updated my question with the new information regarding using fold.

Comment: I added some more observations. (I also had some not very useful observations, which I deleted.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never realized that :: is adding to the beginning of a list, but that makes sense and explains why we always do a head element :: a list tail. Makes sense why I would have to build it backwards and reverse it.

Answer (score 2):

You are nearly there. As you have observed, since we get list of lists, we need to flatten it to get a final list. `List.concat` function does exactly that:

```
let add_dbls list =
  let l =
    match list with
    | h::t -> List.map (fun a -> [a;(a*2)]) list
    | [] -> []
  in
  List.concat l
```

Here is the updated function that that computes the output that you require.
Now the output of `add_dbls [2;5;8] = [2;4;5;10;8;16]`. 
Although this works, it probably isn't efficient as it allocates a new list per item in your original list. Below are variations of the same function with different characteristics which depend on the  size of `l`.

```
(* Safe version - no stack overflow exception. Less efficient(time and size) than add_dbls3 below. *)
let add_dbls2 l =
  List.fold_left
    (fun acc a -> (a*2)::a::acc)
    []
    l
  |> List.rev

(* Fastest but unsafe - stack overflow exception possible if 'l' is large - fold_right is not tail-recursive. *)
let add_dbls3 l =
  List.fold_right
    (fun a acc -> a::(a*2)::acc)
    l
    []
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm actually trying to use my own fold and map functions to gain a better understanding of them before I use the ones provided for me. Your second function explains exactly what I was working on!

Comment: Or as of OCaml 4.10.0, [`List.concat_map`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALconcat_map).